# Low wifi signal in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I installed Ubuntu yesterday, so I'm trying to get used to it.

I'm really close to my router, but my wifi signal gets too low. Sometimes I'm in Facebook or Youtube and the signal is high, almost full, but it is usually in one or two bars, and sometimes none.

I can use Internet normally, I can watch videos and stuff, but the problem is when I try to update something or Ubuntu is downloading stuff, the downloads get stuck or get cancelled telling me that I should check my connection.

How can I fix this? I should be getting a really good signal, I'm really close to my router, my phone has full signal, and a notebook with Windows 7 has full signal here too.

Sorry my bad English and I hope you can help me.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Done! I added lspci -knn , I couldn't add grep Net -A2

Comment: This is one command, not two.

Comment: I tried to put it all but when I press enter nothing happens, it just gives me "juan@juan-System-Product-Name:~$" again (Juan is my name)

Comment: Do you use a USB adapter?

Comment: Yes, I use a USB adapter, it's tl-wn723n

Comment: How could we guess that? Then remove you pasted before and add `lsusb` output.

Comment: Alright, done! I'm really sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use my TL-WN725N](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332210/cant-use-my-tl-wn725n), also [Drivers for TP-LINK TL-WN725N Nano USB Wireless N adapter](/q/381574), and [tp-link wirless n, TL-WN725N](/q/295476)

Comment: Well, he couldn't use it, I could use it, I just had bad signal

Comment: @DavidFoerster It is a different question and a bit different solution. It iw better to mark those answers as duplicates of this. Larry Finger added `dkms.conf` since that times and this installation is much better.

Comment: @Pilot6: Thanks. That sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the driver. Connect to internet some other way and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

Comment: Alright, I did all of that, it seems to be working but my signal is gray, but it works so far

Comment: What do you mean "signal is gray"?

Comment: Uhm, I will try to explain, sorry my bad english. The signal icon, that one in the task bar next to the volume icon, is gray, it doesn't has the bars in white, all the bars are gray. Or it is like that?

Comment: I think the indication will return after reboot.